# C++/CLI Convert unmanaged native C++ list into a managed C++/CLI List

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I have a C++ list which contains a struct.  My C++/CLI project consumes the native C++.  I would like to return a managed list to my C# project.  How can I convert my C++ list into a managed list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need a `ref class` that acts as a wrapper around the `struct` for each item. You can store a pointer to the `struct` as a field in the `ref class`. Let's call it `StructWrapper`.

Then you need something to represent the list. The most flexible way to do that is to expose an `IEnumerable<StructWrapper>`. Either write your own implementation (not as bad as it sounds) or just load all the items into a `List<StructWrapper>` and return that.